# Unable to Import Requests , pandas or any library

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, package

I have installed python 2.7.11 version because the script that I want to run is version specific.
but when I am trying to import packages i.e. requests module I'm not getting it. PFB the error.

Can someone please help with this?
[image]

- I tried Pycharm and various other IDE I'm facing the same issue.
- already disconnect my VPN and tried so it is also not the issue.

if I try it manually don't know the manual process??

Comment: Can you provide more info? How are you trying to run the script? How are you making sure requests isn't installed?

Comment: You need to install a version suitable for Python 2.

Comment: Can you add the `-v` flag for your pip command and add the output you get to your question? Hit the [edit] button and copy/paste the complete output into your question. Please don't use screenshots

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed the `requests` library, please check its version. it should be compatible with the Python version you are using (python 2.7.11).

you can try installing `pip install requests==2.7.0` and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: still the same issue only showing collecting request but still its downloaded.

Comment: what's the actual error you're getting? can you please add the exact error to your question above?